# Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt 1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} + \dots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}{\ln (n)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt 1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} + \dots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}{\ln (n)}$

Can we apply  Stolz-Cesaro?

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac {\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} {{\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)}}$ =
$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt n - \sqrt {n+1}}{\sqrt n \sqrt{n+1}\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}$ = $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1-\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}}{\sqrt{n+1}\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}$

What can I do from here?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{\sqrt 1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} + \dots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} -2\sqrt{n}$ is bounded above and below

Comment: ... and so $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt 1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} + \dots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}{\ln (n)} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{2\sqrt{n}}{\ln (n)} = +\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is $+\infty$.

You made an error in the first step. Applying Stolz-Cesaro, you should rather consider:

\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{\frac 1{\sqrt{n+1}}}{\ln{(n+1)}-\ln n}
& = & \frac 1{\sqrt{(n+1)}}\cdot \frac 1{\ln \left(1+\frac 1 n\right)}\\
& = & \frac n{\sqrt{(n+1)}}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{\frac 1n}{\ln \left(1+\frac 1 n\right)}}_{\stackrel{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}1} \\
& \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} & +\infty
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: You are right. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @vyavarignut You are welcome. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Option:

$n/√n < 1/√1+1/√2....+1/√n;$

$\dfrac{√n}{2 \log (√n)} < \dfrac{1/√1+1/√2+...1/√n}{\log n};$

$(1/2) \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{√n}{\log √n} = $?